# Save a page as a pdf and upload to server

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I have web forms that I have my staff fill out for various purposes that I would like to save the completed form itself and turn it into a PDF, which I can then upload to my database and store for reference.

For example, here is a form that I would like to be able to save as a pdf after the user has inputted the fields:

http://jsfiddle.net/davellan/e7msc41a/

### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 rcshadow">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rcpage">
                    <div class="row">
                         <h1>Add New Contact</h1>

                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Contact Information:</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form role="form" id="newprofile" name="newprofile" style="display:inline" action="" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="Update" value="true" />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
                                                <input required class="form-control" type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="MiddleName">Middle Name:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="MiddleName" name="MiddleName" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
                                                <input required class="form-control" type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="Email" name="Email" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="Phone1">Home Phone:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="tel" id="Phone1" name="Phone1" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="Phone2">Cell Phone:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="tel" id="Phone2" name="Phone2" value="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="StreetAddress1">Address 1:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="StreetAddress1" name="StreetAddress1" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="StreetAddress2">Address 2:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="StreetAddress2" name="StreetAddress2" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="City">City:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="City" name="City" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="State">State:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="State" name="State" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="PostalCode">Zip Code:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="PostalCode" name="PostalCode" value="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="LeadType">Select Lead Type:</label>
                                                <select required class="form-control" id="LeadType" name="LeadType" value="options">
                                                    <option value="">Lead Type</option>
                                                    <option value="14587">Adult MMA</option>
                                                    <option value="14589">Kids MMA</option>
                                                    <option value="14591">Bootcamp</option>
                                                    <option value="8673">Shooting Club</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="ProfileButton" name="ProfileButton" type="submit" value="Add New Profile">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

### CSS

```
/* START
** Div and container setup */

/* Set a max-width for horizontal fluid layout and make it centered */
 .container-fluid {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 970px;
}
/* Make background highlightable */
 .highlightable:hover {
    background-color:#e7e7e7;
}
/* Spacer */
 .spacer {
    padding:10px;
}
/* Padding */
 .padding10 {
    padding:10px;
}
/* Shadow for Page Outline */
 .rcshadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}
/* Page Outline */
 .rcpage {
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:10px 30px 20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}
/* Body */
 body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:verdana, arial, 'sans serif';
    background-color:#3b607e;
    color:#000000;
}
tr.clickable-row {
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* END
** Div and container setup */

/* START 
** Typography */
 h1 {
    font-size:2em;
    color:#739CBF;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 2px;
    text-align:center;
}
h2 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:#3b607e;
    font-weight:bold;
}
h3 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
h4 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
/* Used for search text */
 .smalltext {
    font-size:xx-small;
    color:#ABABAB;
}
.error {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
/* text for footer that goes against background */
 .bgtext {
    color: silver;
}
/* Form Error Code */
 input.error {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
/* Form Error Code */
 label.error {
    color: red;
}
/* END 
** Typography */
```

The resources that I have searched around all seem to be very old projects from 2007 to 2011.

The workflow that would be ideal is as follows:
1. User fills out a webform
2. Upon submitting webform, the page is rendered into a pdf
3. The pdf is then uploaded to my database

What would be the best way of accomplishing this using php or javascript?

Comment: store the DATA, whats the point of storeing a pdf?

Comment: @Dagon - For reference. I can go back and see how this form was filled out. The fields that are in form can be changed from time to time and independently, so knowing how each form was filled out lets me know when a certain value changed.

I suppose it doesn't have to be a pdf. An image file would do as well. As long as I can go back and see how it was filled out it doesn't make too much of a difference.

Comment: even more reason to store the actual  data in a db. ever tried to programmatically compare 2 pdf's?. Image? that makes less sense

Comment: @Dagon - I do store the data. I also want to store the pdf. To make it clearer, suppose in one form someone fills out all the fields in the above form. Then, someone updates the info and changes the phone number. My CRM that has the database doesn't let me know what was changed and what the previous state was. So having a PDF "snapshot" lets me know what happened before.

Comment: how do you plan to compare the pdf's ?

Comment: I would have one of my staff members look at them. This is not something that would have be to programmed to compare the PDFs. My CRM has a limited set of fields, so trying to store many variables is not ideal in my situation unfortunately, which I was I would like to store this forms as PDFs. I can attach PDFs to contact records in my CRM, so that makes it easy.

The above form is not a good example of the type of form I would actually store (it was just a simple example).

Answer (score -1):

As Dagon pointed out below there is a PHP class called TCPDF (which has a link in the comment) that should work for you.

Anther option is [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), which is also a PHP class that lets you make PDF files. This seemed to work for a similar question [Best way to create a PDF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132015/best-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-php). They have even have a [tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php) page. Warning: This option has been updated recently.

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: FPDF has not been updated for 4 years, its not recommended. http://www.tcpdf.org/index.php is generally considered the best (at this moment in time)

Comment: 2011-06-18 vs 2015-04-29